# Android Studio - ViewPager slider issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I just created a simple android app - text(screen) slider via ViewPager, but the first page should contain also a logo/image. How can I prevent that the image is not copying to the other pages?

```
    public int[] slide_images = {
            R.drawable.logo
    };

    public String[] slide_paragraph = {
            "Lorem Ipsum 1",
            "Lorem Ipsum 2",
            "Lorem Ipsum 3"

    };

 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slide_paragraph.length;
    }


@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout, container, false);

        ImageView slideImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_logo);
        TextView slideParagraph = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.slide_paragraph);

        slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
        slideParagraph.setText(slide_paragraph[position]);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this part of instatiateItem method

```
slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
```

to

```
if(position == 0)
    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_images[position]);
```

Comment: Yep, but the image is still copying to other pages/slides. I want to have it only on the first slide.